# Error "handshake failure" When Using Certificate in EAP-TTLS Freeradius

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, radius, freeradius

I follow the instruction in file **README** in **raddb/certs**

and create **ca.pem** , **server.pem** and **client.p12**

After That, I extracted **ca.pem** and **client.p12** and installed them on my mobile,

Also configure the access point to redirect to my server which have the Radius

But when i select the Root CA which called "Eurostar" in "CA certificate"

[image]

i have this error,

```
ERROR: (16)  ERROR: eap_ttls : TLS Alert write:fatal:handshake failure
Error: tls: TLS_accept: Error in SSLv3 read client certificate B
Error: SSL: SSL_read failed in a system call (-1), TLS session fails.
Auth: (16) Login incorrect (eap_ttls: TLS Alert write:fatal:handshake failure): [ahmed/<via Auth-Type = EAP>] (from client Bermawy-home port 17 cli 3C-47-11-75-49-2C)
```

Answer (score -1):

can you choose **PAP** for *Phase 2 Authentication* please? 
I hope that will work for you.
Let me know please.

Comment: In you access point, did you choose encryption type as WPA2-Enterprise/AES, 802.1x . This error is related to FreeRadius EAP encryption type. I have struggled with it so many times. I am positive to solve that problem always.